# Large File (1-3GB) upload to SQL via WebApi

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I have a JS/HTML5 front end that calls a C# WebAPI to upload a large file (1-3GB) that needs to be encrypted and then stored in a SQL DB.

My restrictions are that I can't store file unecnrypted and it can't be stored outside of SQL.  I also can't use SQL FileStream.

For the WebAPI, I disabled the BufferStream (via overriding WebHostBufferPolicySelector) to take care of any memory exceptions.  This allows me to upload files directly to disk without increasing the memory footprint significantly.

I would like to store the series of encrypted chunks that make up the file in order in rows in a SQL table.  Then I could pull the chunks out, decrypt them, and stream them back to the user when requested.

I do not know how I can take a multi-data part message, encrypt the chunks, and write it to rows in the database.  Can someone point me in the right direction with how I can do this?

Comment: Large files are not stored in a DB, the are stored in the file system and the path to the file is stored in the DB.

Comment: @zaph - I understand that files in general are not stored in the database.  Unfortunately, I don't get to write the requirements for what I work on.  

As I mentioned above, I THOUGHT about using FileStream but didn't think I could encrypt it without loading the file into memory so I decided against that (bigger reason I didnt is because it stored files the way you mentioned).

That's why I thought about storing the individual chunks and encrypting each one of those.

Comment: The next issue is how the encryption key will be protected, that is kept secret from someone who gains admin access to the DB—that is how attacks occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  So you've solved the issue of WebAPI not running out of RAM.  But the next concern is that you've got to pass the data to SQL Server.  You can pipe the request stream through any of the .NET stream encryptors, but then it's gotta go somewhere after that.

I suggest you do something like:

Request stream -> encryptor -> custom stream

The custom stream will be responsible for sending data to sql server in *chunks*.  You can fine tune the size of the chunks but it's essentially so that you don't try to send a sql command with a 1GB or more argument size.  Your custom stream sql command will break the upload into chunks of bytes, given a fixed buffer size.  When the buffer gets over a certain amount, you write a row to SQL Server, flush the buffer, and wait for more to come in from the encryptor stream.  The rows that get written will be tied together with some sort of ID, and of course, a sequence number that will tell you the order to use when re-assembling them.

When you want to send the data back, you just do this again, but in reverse.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need..I'm just not sure how to do it.  I'm guessing that to do this I would override GetStream of MultiStreamProvider to gain access to the actual file stream.  In that method, I would run the request stream through the crypto stream to encrypt it.  After that and still in the overriden GetStream method, I would create a new custom stream instance that takes the crypto stream as input and in the write implementation of the custom stream, I would write the stream to sql.  Does that sound right?  How would I do the buffer monitoring?  

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have the gist of this. Make sure to check for any data in the buffer inside of your custom streams dispose method. I'm not really sure what you're looking for as far as monitoring is concerned.

Comment: I have a follow up post to this where I believe I have most of the process working.  The issue I'm having now is that I can't re-assemble the file to download properly.  Do you mind taking a look at what I put together here: [new stackoverflow question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616670/large-file-download-from-sql-via-webapi-after-custom-multipartformdatastreamprov?noredirect=1&lq=1)